# Merge php array merge without removing array key

Tags: php

I have arrays like this.

```
Array ( 
[title] => Array ( [0] => Value1 ) 
[description] => Array ( [0] => Value1 )
)
```

but i want the arrays to be look like this.

```
Array ( [title] => Value1 [description] => Value1 )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply

```
$array = array_map(function ($element) {
   return $element[0];
}, $array);
```

Test: http://3v4l.org/qd2eG

Comment: Can you please explain a little how i can use it.

I have arrays like this.

$array_title = $class['title'];
$array_desc = $class['description'];